# Combine Multiple JS files into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL redirection JS code on a number of pages i.e Mon.html, Tue.html etc, I want to combine it into one file and still redirect the user to the mobile version of the page depending on their screen width e.g

```js
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "../m/days/mon.html";
  }
```

This means that I have many JS files with a respective `window.location`
I'm trying to have one JS file with all the necessary redirects.

Comment: I'm confused on your goal here - why are you trying to redirect a user to *3 different pages* at the same time?

Comment: You have the same condition in all of th redircts. If you don't add any other conditions to separate you can't avoid multiple redirs.

Comment: I think you need to make one check depending on `screen.width` and multi if-else on the day instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```js
var screen_width = screen.width;

$(function() {
  if ($('body').is('.index') && (screen_width <= 800)) {
    window.location = "m/index.html";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map current location to a redirect.

```
if(screen.width <= 800) {
    switch(window.location) {
        case firstLocation:
            window.location = firstRedirect;
        case secondLocation:
            window.location = secondRedirect;
       // other redirect cases
       default:
           throw new Error('no redirect assigned to current location');
    }
}
```

Or if redirects has the same pattern you can modify current location according to that pattern. That would be more preferable, as it doesn't contain lots of hardcoded locations, so you don't have to update it manually every time.

```
if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = '../m/' + window.location;
}
```

Comment: Please note that without additional checks you will have a cyclic redirect if you have the same script in redirection target page.

Comment: interesting how do i reference 'firstLocation' ?